# Larger Regex Javascript for Date and time close to keywords, part for days missing first digit

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my regex: https://regex101.com/r/fBq3Es/1

`(audiência|sessão virtual)(?:.(?!audiência|sessão virtual|até))*([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])\s*de\s*([^\s]+)\s*de\s*((19|20)?\d\d)(?:,|\s*)*(?:,|\s*)*(?:\S*)?(?:,|\s*)*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(h|:|\s*horas*\s*e\s*|\s*horas*\s*)([0-5]?[0-9])?`

It should pick something like this:

Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Audiência em 24 de Julho de 2022 às 16:00 horas Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum

And extract the `"24 de Julho de 2022 às 16:00 horas"`

its taking only the `"4 de Julho de 2022 às 16:00 horas"` missing the first digit for some reason.

The problem is, `"9 de Janeiro de 2021"` (with no leading zeroes or any other numbers) is also a possible input and answer.

I asked this question a few days ago and got the answer that the logic for the date bit of my regex is working (but only when taken out of the larger expression) "`([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])`", I've tried changing positions, different combinations, to make the zero fixed and add another or `([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-9])`, none of them worked.

So why does it "Eat" the first day digit, when its inside the full expression?

A demo of it is running as said on regex101.com with the config set to ECMAScript (JavaScript) and global multiline and case insensitive.

As they questioned me where this is being used, this bit regex was taken from a workflow that has a text parser "Module" that accept regex with those configurations, I can only feed it a regex, no different programing languages allowed.

See [the current regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fBq3Es/1).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if you look at the regex101 demo, on the group 2, the output is only 4 and not 24 as it should.

I'm trying to grab the specific date that is very close to the word "audiência", from a larger text that can contain other dates in it.

the one closest to the word "audiência" is needed to schedule events and meetings.

Comment: First get the whole matching string and then split accordingly [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fe1wIu/1)

Comment: Also I don't quite need the date to be validated as a date (I know this is a big problem with regex), it having a close by "time" and being close to the "keyword" is enough to validate it as a date, and even if it was a weird date like 31/02/2099 it would still be a valid output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a space:

```
(audiência|sessão virtual)(?:(?!audiência|sessão virtual|até).)* ([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])\s*de\s*([^\s]+)\s*de\s*((19|20)?\d\d)(?:,|\s*)*(?:,|\s*)*\S*(?:,|\s*)*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(h|:|\s*horas*\s*e\s*|\s*horas*\s*)([0-5]?[0-9])?
```

The problem with your regex is that the `2` is found as part of `(audiência|sessão virtual)(?:.(?!audiência|sessão virtual|até))*` and `([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])` allows a single digit.

A question mark also works

```
(audiência|sessão virtual)(?:(?!audiência|sessão virtual|até).)*?([1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9])\s*de\s*(\S+)\s*de\s*((19|20)?\d\d)(?:,|\s*)*(?:,|\s*)*\S*(?:,|\s*)*([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(h|:|\s*horas*\s*e\s*|\s*horas*\s*)([0-5]?[0-9])?
```

`(?:.(?!audiência|sessão virtual|até))*` is greedy. It takes as much as possible including the `2`. `(?:.(?!audiência|sessão virtual|até))*?` is lazy. It takes as few as possible.

Comment: The space worked as a charm, the edit to a lazy search worked too

Comment: Note `(?:,|\s*)*(?:,|\s*)*\S*(?:,|\s*)*` will cause catastrophic backtracking one day. Also, always use the dot after the lookahead in tempered greedy tokens.